# How to extract patterns from a string in linux

Tags: regex, bash, macos, awk, sed

I have a string with a continuous (not separated by new line) list of execution times taken by tests. It is printed in the format:

```
<execution time> s -----> <Testcase name><optionally:[Parameters used by test]> <execution time> s ... <Testcase name>
```

Eg :

```
1.2 s -----> Testa[0. param1] 2.4 s -----> Testb 3 s -----> Testc
```

This gives me the execution time of each test.

Problem extracting this is I can't split it using space and the assign time = split[i] and testcase = split[i+3] (as in case of Testa, I get extra parameters).

I want to be able to add a new line at the beginning of each time duration and extract just the time and the test case name.

I have tried to get the time by doing

```
 sed -r  's/^[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*/\1/' /tmp/tmp
```

but I am using MacOS which doesn't support sed -r.

Is there a better way to extract the times taken and the corresponding testcase names from the string?

For the example provided, the output can be of the format :

```
 1.2,Testa[0. param1]

 2.4,Testb

 3,Testc
```

PS : I cant change the input file pattern

Comment: A single example of your input is not by any stretch of the imagination a specification of which formats that input can take -- and a specification is what we need. If you don't have a full spec, at least you can come up with a large range of examples that covers the corner cases.

Comment: Corrected the 2. Thanks!

Comment: *"but I am using MacOS which doesn't support sed -r"*: It isn't a problem, you can use `E` in place of `r` to have the Extended Regular Expression(ERE), or you can use the BRE (Basic Regular Expression) syntax.

Comment: You should also show your expected output

Answer (score 3):

```
re='([[:digit:].]+ s) ----->([^>]*)(>(.*))?$'

s='1.2 s -----> Testa[0. param1] 2.4 s -----> Testb 3 s -----> Testc'

while [[ $s =~ $re ]]; do           # apply POSIX ERE in $re to string in $s
  curr_time=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}      # first match group is curr_time
  curr_name=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}      # second match group is curr_name
  curr_name=${curr_name%' -----'}   # strip trailing dashes from curr_name
  curr_name=${curr_name% * s}       # strip time of next item from curr_name
  echo "${curr_time% s},$curr_name" # emit output
  s="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}" # strip completed content from string
done
```

...emits, with your given input:

```
1.2 s  Testa[0. param1]
2.4 s  Testb
3 s  Testc
```

---

Breaking down the regex `([[:digit:].]+ s) ----->([^>]*)(>(.*))?$` into its components:

- `([[:digit:].]+ s)` defines the first match group, which will populate `BASH_REMATCH[1]`. It matches at least one digit or period, followed by a space and a `s`.
- `----->` matches that literal string.
- `([^>]*)` matches everything *prior to* the next `>`, forming `BASH_REMATCH[2]`; we'll be extracting the name of the test from here.
- `(>(.*))?$` matches a literal `>` and any other content remaining until the end of the line, allowing that yet-unprocessed content to be captured for the next iteration through the loop.

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much. Can you please explain this?

Comment: I've added comments to the code. If you need further explanation, could you detail exactly what's not clear?

Answer (score 1):

I'm really no expert in Perl but PCRE has [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=...)` feature:

```
$ perl -ne 's/ ----->/,/g; s/ (?=[0-9](\.[0-9])* s)/\n/g;print' file
1.2 s, Testa[0. param1]
2.4 s, Testb
3 s, Testc
```

- `s/ ----->//g` remove those arrowy thingies
- `s/ (?=[0-9](\.[0-9])* s)/\n/g` replace space if followed by time looking thing (lookahead)

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="," }
{
    cnt = 0
    gsub(/----->/,"\n")
    while ( match($0,/\s*([0-9.]+) s \n ([^\n]+)$/,a) ) {
        flds[++cnt] = a[1] OFS a[2]
        $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
    }
    for (i=cnt; i>0; i--) {
        print flds[i]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
1.2,Testa[0. param1]
2.4,Testb
3,Testc
```